# Bootstrap - how to change order of displaying columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, push, pull

I have problem with ordering colums on sm and xs large on bootstrap. I'd like to change ordering from "1","2","3" to "1","3","2" on sm and xs resolutions:

http://imageshack.com/a/img923/8600/DF8LGA.png

I tried to set col-xs-push-12 to "2" column and col-xs-push-12 to "3" column but it doesn't work. Please help me.

Here are my files:
http://www.speedyshare.com/6B6Fv/public-html.rar

and code:

```
      <div class="header-bot">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <a class="logo-1 hidden-sm hidden-xs" href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo-md.png" alt="Logo"/>
                    </a>
                    <a class="visible-sm" href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo-sm.png" alt="Logo"/>
                    </a>
                    <a class="visible-xs" href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo-xs.png" alt="Logo"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 col-xs-push-12">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="hidden-xs icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="hidden-xs icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="hidden-xs icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="visible-xs glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                            </button>
                            <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Menu</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="ul-main nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#">new</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">designers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">women</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">men</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">clearence</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </div>
                <div class="header-user col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-pull-12">
                    <div class="cart hidden-xs">
                        <p>Your cart</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="basket">
                        <p>0 Items | $ 0</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the pull / push on the higher screen size, like so

```
<div class="header-user col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-md-push-7">
   ...

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-md-pull-3">
   ...
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/73jpt545/